# Xmonad GUI on debian

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, gui, xmonad

I followed [this guide](https://wiki.debian.org/Xmonad) to install Xmonad GUI on my debian 7.1. Installation completed successfully after executing:

```
aptitude install xmonad libghc6-xmonad-dev libghc6-xmonad-contrib-dev
```

After executing of:

```
$ xmonad
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
deepsy@deepsypc:~$ xmonad
/home/deepsy/.xmonad/xmonad-x86_64-linux: executeFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
Major opcode of failed request:  2 (X_ChangeWindowAttributes)
Serial number of failed request:  7
Current serial number in output stream:  8
```

I've tried to `apt-get purge xmonad` and reinstall it with `apt-get install xmonad`, but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are already have a window manager running. Try `xmonad --replace`!